# How to reference compact framework 3.9 class library in the full framework 3.5 class library

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I have a class library that targets .NET Compact framework 3.9 and I have the class library that targets .NET Framework 3.5. Now, when I'm adding a reference to .NET CF 3.9 library in .NET 3.5 library all the types from CF library are not resolved and I cant use them. Is there a way to make it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Your only "solution" is to create two separate projects, one for the full framework and one for the CF.  If you put the project files in the same folder and manually edit the project files to include *.cs, you can at least have them always contain the same source files, but there's no binary compatibility or way to get the CF assembly to load in the full framework.

Comment: Actually, I resolved this problem, but maybe you misunderstood the question - I have a project in CF 3.9(class library) and I have project in .NET 3.5(even 4.5 can be) and I reference CF project in .NET project. Actually, everything works perfectly and it was a problem with Resharper, which couldn't resolve the referenced assembly. Anyway, thanks for input, because it's quite difficult to find someone who can answer some questions about CF

Comment: So you have a CF assembly being referenced by a full framework assembly and when it's deployed, it actually works?  That would be rare (though not impossible).  The primary issue is that the CF compiler doesn't know or care about full-framework stuff.  If any call you make needs to call down into coredll.dll, the CF compiler will put that into your assembly (or more specifically pull in a reference to another CF assembly that does) and at run time you'll get a TypeLoadException.  It's only going to happen at run time, not at compile time, so tread very carefully.